# Changing orientation of React-Native app shows strange white rectangle on top (IOS only)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm having something strange happening to an app I'm working on. Whenever I rotate the device on IOS to landscape, a white rectangle appears on top:

[image]

Even when removing everything on this specific page causes the white block to show, so I suspect it might be deeper (perhaps Redux or React-navigation?) but I'm not sure. I tried changing the background-color in the AppDelegate.m as well, but it shows no difference.

Anyone else experienced this or has any idea what might cause it?

Comment: Be sure to check that all components at top level have background color of your dark background color.

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me! I found the solution in the end, I'll post it below incase someone else that the same issue

Answer (score 2):

For anyone dealing with this, I found the issue and solution. It was related to react-navigation. In my stackNavigator I had put the header to null, but when rotating to landscape, this header is still there (the white area). Solution is to put the header headerTintColor and headerStyle backgroundColor to 'transparant'! :)